# Python array algorithm

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I'm working on writing a function where an array is given:

```
arrayA = [2,3,1]
```

The function needs to return a new array where:

```
newArray = [2,5,6]
```

This is almost like a Fibonacci function.

```
newArray[0] = arrayA[0]
newArray[1] = arrayA[0] + arrayA[1]
newArray[2] = arrayA[1] + arrayA[2] + arrayA[3]
```

Heres my code so far, but always end up with a empty list. `arrayA` is passed in as parameter.

```
def generateNewArray(A):
    A=[]
    newArray=[]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        newArray[i]=A[i]+A(i+1)
    return  newArray
```

Comment: What is the point of `A=[]`?

Comment: @Jess it is returning an empty list because you declare A=[] which basically says, empty my list when you start your function

Comment: well thats certainly one of the problems :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print [sum(A[:i]) for i in range(1,len(A)+1)]
```

I guess ... I think theres actually a **cumulative sum** builtin somewhere ... or maybe its in numpy

```
numpy.cumsum(A)
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a functional programming pattern:

Try this:

```
def generateNewArray(inputArray):
    return map(lambda x: sum(inputArray[:x]), xrange(1, len(inputArray) + 1))
```

For example:

```
In [7]: generateNewArray([2, 3, 1])
Out[7]: [2, 5, 6]
```